# Proving that group objects in the category of groups are abelian groups.

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, abelian-groups

The following is the definition of a group object that I am using:

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category. An object $G\in\mathcal{C}$ is a group object in $\mathcal{C}$ if for all $X\in\mathcal{C}$, the set Hom$(X,G)$ has a group structure such that the map Hom$(\ \boldsymbol{\cdot}\ ,G)$ defined on objects as $X\mapsto$Hom$(X,G)$ and on morhpisms as $f\mapsto f^*$, is a contravariant functor $\mathcal{C}\rightarrow$ Grp.

How do you prove, using the above definition, that the group objects in Grp are abelian groups?

Comment: Maybe not an _exact_ duplicate, because your definition of "group object" is different from the one in this question, but definitely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33571/group-objects-in-category-of-groups. The basic idea, though, is that you want to show $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ is a homomorphism. But this is only true of abelian groups. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872952/prove-a-group-g-is-abelian-if-and-only-if-the-map-g-rightarrow-g-given-by).

Comment: Hi, thank you. I'm just not sure how to show that for a group object in Grp, the inverse map must be a homomorphism.